# Drop Unique Constraint on Table Column without Knowing the Constraint Name

Tags: sql, oracle10g, unique-constraint

In Oracle 10g, how can I drop a unique constraint on a column without knowing the name of the constraint (e.g. a system generated name, which won't necessarily be the same across database instances)? Dropping and recreating the table isn't an option. Is it possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can retrieve the constraint's name with:

```
SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'xxx'
AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'U'
```

You can for instance create a stored procedure that executes the previous sql, stores its result in a variable and uses this variable in `ALTER TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT`

**EDIT: e.g.:**

```
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (
    SELECT TABLE_NAME, CONSTRAINT_NAME
    FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'xxx'
    AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'U') LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE REPLACE(REPLACE(
      'ALTER TABLE #TABLE# DROP CONSTRAINT #CON#'
      ,'#TABLE#',r.TABLE_NAME)
      ,'#CON#',r.CONSTRAINT_NAME);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked nicely for my purposes. Though I can see that in some cases special care needs to be taken, like when you want to keep some unique constraints and drop others, since you can't simply zero in on specific columns involved in a constraint.